# Formula Application-defined error or object defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run the code, but facing

> Application-defined error / object defined error

on the line: `.Range("JI2:JM2").Formula = strFormulas` Please help me to resolve the issue.

```
Sub Copy_Reason()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim lRow, p, q As Long

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sum_Reasons")
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox lRow

    Dim strFormulas(1 To 5) As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sum_Reasons")
        strFormulas(1) = "=IFERROR(LARGE($B2:$JH2,ROW($1:$1)),"")"
        strFormulas(2) = "=IFERROR(LARGE($B2:$JH2,ROW($2:$2)),"")"
        strFormulas(3) = "=IFERROR(LARGE($B2:$JH2,ROW($3:$3)),"")"
        strFormulas(4) = "=IFERROR(LARGE($B2:$JH2,ROW($4:$4)),"")"
        strFormulas(5) = "=IFERROR(LARGE($B2:$JH2,ROW($5:$5)),"")"

        .Range("JI2:JM2").Formula = strFormulas
        .Range("JI2:JM" & lRow).FillDown
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
strFormulas(1) = "=IFERROR(LARGE($B2:$JH2,ROW($1:$1)),"")"
```

(and the others) should be

```
strFormulas(1) = "=IFERROR(LARGE($B2:$JH2,ROW($1:$1)),"""")"
```

You need to escape the `"` by doubling them up.

Comment: OP is putting the formula over a range of columns (`JI` to `JM`), so the Transpose is not required.

Comment: @chrisneilsen -  Thanks I didn't think that should be necessary but somehow got things backwards...

Comment: @TimWilliams - Thank you very much. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Core issue is not escaping the `"`s as others mentioned.

There are a few other issues too, so see inline comments below

```
Sub Copy_Reason()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    ' specify type for all variables, otherwise they will be Variants
    Dim lRow As Long, p As Long, q As Long
    Dim strFormulas(1 To 5) As Variant

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sum_Reasons")
    ' use the worksheet object you just created
    With sh
        ' get last row from the required sheet (as it was, it was getting lRow form the Active Sheet)
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        MsgBox lRow
        strFormulas(1) = "=IFERROR(LARGE($B2:$JH2,ROW($1:$1)),"""")"  ' escape the "
        strFormulas(2) = "=IFERROR(LARGE($B2:$JH2,ROW($2:$2)),"""")"
        strFormulas(3) = "=IFERROR(LARGE($B2:$JH2,ROW($3:$3)),"""")"
        strFormulas(4) = "=IFERROR(LARGE($B2:$JH2,ROW($4:$4)),"""")"
        strFormulas(5) = "=IFERROR(LARGE($B2:$JH2,ROW($5:$5)),"""")"

        .Range("JI2:JM" & lRow).Formula = strFormulas ' FillDown is not needed, this will update the relative references as required
        ' Note a 1D array will apply correctly to a single row as it does here
    End With
End Sub
```